# Declaring a 2D array in a struct without knowing the size in a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

Can I do this in C?

I have this code that gives me the error

```
ERROR
minesweeper.c:19:19: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
      int *boardSpaces = (int *)malloc(newBoard.rows * newBoard.columns * sizeof(int));

typedef struct boards
{
    int rows, columns;
    int *boardSpaces = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(int));
} Board;
```

But when I put it in my main it works just fine.

Can I declare this in a struct, or is it just I am missing something?

Comment: No, it's invalid. In C you can not have any member initialisers within a struct definition.

Comment: If you like, you can tell us what you are trying to achieve and someone will probably be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant run function on the variables in the struct like that.

The short answer is because `rows` and `columns` don't have any value at compile time.

You can do this, in this function, create_board and delete_board are essentially mimicking constructor and destructor from c++, but you have to manually call them.

```
struct Board
{
    int rows, columns;
    int *boardSpaces; // memory will be allocated when we need it
};

/* create a board with a given size, as memory is dynamically allocated, it must be freed when we are done */
struct Board createBoard(int rows, int columns){
    struct Board b;
    b.rows = rows;
    b.columns = columns;
    b.boardSpaces = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(int));
    return b;
}
void delete_board(Board *b){
    free(b->boardSpaces);
}

int main(void){
    struct Board b = createBoard(2,3);
    do_stuff_with(&b);
    delete_board(&b);

}
```

/* I didnt run this through a compiler, so forgive typos */

Comment: Returning the initialized structure is poor style.  Even C++ constructors don't do that.  Better take a pointer to a structure allocated by the caller and return a success/failure indicator that could report a memory allocation failure.

Comment: @chqrlie : I won't deny that, but this gives the basic idea of how to have the struct.

Generally in the C application I work in, any memory failure is unrecoverable, so my general process is to create the struct at the top of the function, and pass it's pointer as an argument to a setup function that returns 0/1, then, on failure, I give a message, and exit the program.

Comment: You should probably use `calloc` to return a consistently initialized board.

Comment: While it is legal C code, it does not teach the OP good practices.